# How do I calculate the integral $\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{xe^{ax}}{(1+ax)^2}dx}$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

If $a>0$, how do I calculate the following integral? $$\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{xe^{ax}}{(1+ax)^2}dx}$$

Comment: By parts. Let $u=xe^{ax}$ and $dv=\frac{dx}{(1+ax)^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{xe^{ax}}{(1+ax)^2}\,dx&=\frac1{a^2}\int_0^a \frac{xe^{x}}{(1+x)^2}\,dx\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{a^2}\int_0^a xe^x \frac{d(1+x)^{-1}}{dx}\,dx\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{a^2}\left(\frac{ae^a}{1+a}-\int_0^a \frac{e^x(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx\right)
\end{align}$$

where the last equality comes from integration by parts with $u=xe^x$ and $v=(1+x)^{-1}$.

And you can finish now.

Comment: Thanks! One (maybe stupid) question: how come you switch from $\int_{0}^{1}$ to $\int_{0}^{a}$? Or rather, what is this concept called, so that I can learn more about it?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  I only made that simple substitution to remove the parameter from the integrand and move it to the limits.